# Django: Cross Site Request Forgery protection doesn't work when using with S3, Cloudfront

Tags: django, ajax, amazon-s3, cross-domain, csrf

I manage static files, including `js` files, using `AWS S3` and `AWS CloudFront`.

I have a code sending `ajax POST` request (to one of my `django` view) and this `a.js` file is located in `S3`.

I realized that I'm faced with sort of cross domain issues, so I copied and pasted some codes in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax. Here is my `js` code:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/orders/pay-check/',
    data: {
        imp_uid : rsp.imp_uid,
        merchant_uid : rsp.merchant_uid
    }, // form date가 아니기 때문에, 맨위에 ajax cookie 세팅을 해줘야함
    success: function(data) {
        ...
    }
});
```

But it occurs `csrf_token` missing errors! So I looked this code in detail and tried to edit some part of code:

**First way**: Add `POST` in `csrfSafeMethod` and remove `this.crossdomain`.

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|POST|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

**Second way**: Just Add `POST` in `csrfSafeMethod`:

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|POST|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

**Third way**: Add `POST` in `csrfSafeMethod` and change `!this.crossDomain` to `this.crossDomain`.

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|POST|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

But all of these cases did not work!!....

Really want to get some advices. Thanks.

** Edit **

I got something strange.

If I open `Chorme development tool` console, and print `document.cookie`, its output doesn't include `csrftoken` which is included in my local development environment....only in production environment does not it shown up

Comment: @khbk No, My js file is located in other domain... I used `AWS cdn, s3` for static files, so its url is something like `https://d2md28.cloudfront.net/js/a.js`

Comment: `// these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection`... wait, what?  `POST` almost certainly should **not** be in this list of "safe" methods.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I know, I just tried...cuz only `ajax POST request` didn't work for me

Comment: Oh, I see, you added it while troubleshooting.  Is the django server also behind CloudFront?

Comment: No, My django server is behind different one. It is on `EC2`, so it has different domain.

Comment: I found something strange... I added it in my post